# Red Hat 7 - Amazon EC2 - Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://None/pulp

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, yum

SELinux is running in permissive mode

**yum update** is yielding:

> Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos Webmin
>   | 1.0 kB  00:00:00      Could not retrieve mirrorlist
>   https://None/pulp/mirror/rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os
>   error was 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: None; Name or service
>   not known"

This is a fresh Amazon Red Hat 7 box, with webmin and a LAMP stack.

Comment: rhui could not determine what region your instance is running in. This doesn't look like an SELinux issue. Though, it could have been caused by installing Webmin. Start over with a new instance, and this time, don't install Webmin.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue,
the resolution was that, edit /etc/yum.repos.d/rhui-load-balancers.conf with

```
rhui2-cds01.eu-central-1.aws.ce.redhat.com
rhui2-cds02.eu-central-1.aws.ce.redhat.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I restored the rhui-load-balancers.conf file and that resolve the issue.

**yum.repos.d/rhui-load-balancers.conf**

> rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com
>
> rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com

Comment: Make sure that that is the correct region. If it is not, then you may be charged for data transfer.